# Custom teams app tab working only in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Im currently making a custom teams app for MS Teams that fetches some data (just strings) from my localhost. However, while my app works fine in the browser version of teams, it doesnt work in the Teams application. Nothing even shows up in my custom tab:

[image: Teams application]

However, in the browser version of the visual studio code debug window:
[image: Debug window]

Does anyone know why its only working in the visual studio code debug window? And how do i get it to work in both the browser version and the Teams application?

The code of my app:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      context: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      microsoftTeams.getContext(resolve);
    })
      .then((context) => {
        this.setState({ context });
        //var inputs {}
        const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams({ function: "getDocuments", input: '"'+ context.userPrincipalName + '"',});
        console.log(`userPrincipalName is '${context.userPrincipalName}'`);
        console.log(`teamName is '${context.teamName}'`);
        console.log(`http://localhost/openims/json.php?${queryParameters}`);
        return fetch(`http://localhost/openims/json.php?${queryParameters}`);
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => this.setState({ ...result }))
      .catch((error) => this.setState({ error }))
      .finally(() => this.setState({ isLoaded: true }));
  }
  
  render() {  
    const { error, isLoaded, name, age, city } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (     
        <ul>
          <li>
            {name} {age} {city}
          </li>
        </ul>       
      );
    }
  }

}
export default Tab;
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you're working on localhost, but Teams won't display any content coming from a local address, even if it's secured on https. This is for security reasons. It is possible to -run- the site locally, but you need to use an internet tunneling service so that the local address is exposed, during development, with a fully qualified https internet address. The most common way to do this (you'll see it frequently in docs, samples, etc.) is to use the NGrok tool, which provides a free version. See more at https://ngrok.com/

Comment: Hey Hilton, I get using ngrok when using a localhost, but what tool/command do you use to tunnel your bot from a server accessible on the internet? For instance, I have my bot running on an EC2 Instance with a Fully Qualified Domain and HTTPS so I can change my endpoint to point to that URL? I have a question I am currently asking on Stack that has more clarification that I would love for you to chime in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68479610/messaging-endpoint-in-a-bot-configuration-gulp-serve-vs-gulp-ngrok-serve

Comment: so you don't use -any- "tunneling" concept when it's hosted on a public infrastructure like AWS. When you add your web resource in AWS, it should provision a url for your automatically, and provide it to you. That would be the "base" url, and then the path *within* your site depends on the app itself.

Comment: but don't I need gulp to run the bot on my server?

Comment: The only reason I say that is because if I run `gulp serve` I can only access my app through `http://teams.example.com:3007/`. which is not going to work because it needs to be `https`. That is where I am massively confused.

Comment: Is there anything I have to do concerning port 3007? Do I need to change it?

Comment: no, none of that stuff applies - that's only to be able to "run" a "web server" on your local machine, temporarily, while you're developing. When it's hosted in a permanent web host, like AWS or Azure, they do all that kind of stuff for you. You also need to run on a "special" port like 3007 on your local machine because you can't run a whole bunch of things on the default ports 80 (http) or 443 (https) because other things might be running already on your workstation. In a dedicated cloud host instance, that you create, you know you're the only thing running on that port.

Comment: ugh, that is where I am confused. So right now I have my apache server running and I am not running `gulp` or anything. When I `nmap` port 3007 on my server it is showing the port is closed. It isn't until I run `gulp serve` when the port is then open. From what I can tell the bot is not running on it's own.

Comment: Hilton - Is there any way I can get in touch with you? I will pay you to help me.

Comment: Sure, happy to connect - LinkedIn messaged you

Comment: Sent an email to you